# OpenNI: How to resize depthMap?

Tags: openni

I need to acquire *depth pixels* from `Kinect` at `VGA` resolution (640x480) and then resize the depth map to QVGA (320x240).

Does openNI provide a method for this?

I tried the following:

```
    _depthGenerator.GetMetaData(*_depthMetaData); // THIS WORKS, I CAN DISPLAY THE DEPTH MAP AT VGA RESOLUTION

    _depthMetaData->ReAdjust(320, 240); //IF I DO THIS, THE DEPTH MAP BECOMES FILLED WITH ZEROS
```

So I am kinda lost.

Any help?

Notes: The point is not to receive QVGA from the sensor, is to receive at VGA and then resize.
The point is not to use openCV to resize the depth map, because the interpolation rules corrupt the depth data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what are you trying to achieve here, but I'll give you a possible solution.

you can create another object structure to save this, for example opencv Mat, then drop each even column and even row, and you'll get a resize without interpolation... There is no other way to downscale without interpolation or loosing data...

I hope this helps, if not, comment the answer and I'll try to change it to a better answer

Comment: I was trying to find out if openNI had a method well prepared for depthmap resize, but I guess it has not.
The solution was to resize with interpolation with openCV,and then remove faulty data on the resized depth map.

Comment: Sadly openni is missing nice features like this one :( I will suggest to remove faulty data before the resizing to prevent it to affect the interpolation.

Comment: The thing is that the faulty data exists 'because' of the resize :P